# How change the Ajax pagination (list of pages) to Load More?

Tags: ajax, pagination, octobercms

How change the Ajax pagination (list of pages) to "Load More Button" from the video tutorial - [Making Websites With October CMS - Part 43 - Ajax Pagination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsvcRsPEe4)?

Can you show me how to do this? Below is the code from the video tutorial.

**Page movie-filter-ajax.htm**

```
title = "Filter movies"
url = "/ajax-filter"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0

==
<?
    use Watchlearn\Movies\Models\Movie;
    use Watchlearn\Movies\Models\Genre;
    function onStart() { 
        $this->prepareVars(); 
        $this->prepareYears();
    }
    function onFilterMovies() { $this->prepareVars(); }
    function prepareVars() {
        $options = post('Filter', []);
        $this['movies'] = Movie::listFrontEnd($options);
        $this['genres'] = Genre::all();
        $this['sortOptions'] = Movie::$allowedSortingOptions;
        $this['pages'] = $this['movies']->lastPage();
        $this['page'] = $this['movies']->currentPage();
    }
    function prepareYears() {
        $movies = Movie::all();
        $years = [];
        foreach($movies as $movie){
            $years[] = $movie->year;
        }
        $years = array_unique($years);
        $this['years'] = $years;
    }
?>
==
<h2 class="ui header" style="margin-top:40px;">Filter Movies</h2>
<div class="ui grid">
<div class="five wide column">
{{ form_ajax('onFilterMovies', { update: { 'movies/movies': '#partialMovies', 'movies/paginate': '#partialPaginate' } }) }}
            <div id="MoviesFilter" class="movies-filter ui form">
                <div class="ui segment vertical">
                    <label>Genres</label>
                    {% for genre in genres %}
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="ui checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="Filter[genres][]" value="{{ genre.id }}" />    
                                <label>{{genre.genre_title}}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Year</label>
                        <select class="ui fluid dropdown" name="Filter[year]">
                            <option value="">Select Year</option>
                            {% for year in years|sort %}
                                <option value="{{year}}">{{ year }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Sorting</label>
                        <select class="ui fluid dropdown" name="Filter[sort]">
                            {% for code, option in sortOptions %}
                                <option value="{{code}}">{{ option }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field" id="partialPaginate">
                        {% partial 'movies/paginate' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{ form_close() }}
    </div>
    <div class="eleven wide column">
        <div id="partialMovies">
            {% partial 'movies/movies' %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**{% partial 'movies/paginate' %}**

```
<label>Page</label>
<select class="ui fluid dropdown" name="Filter[page]">
    {% for i in 1..pages %}
        {%  if i == page %}
            <option value="{{page}}" selected>{{ page }}</option>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{i}}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**Model Movie.php**

```
<?php namespace Watchlearn\Movies\Models;
use Model;
/**
 * Model
 */
class Movie extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    /*
     * Disable timestamps by default.
     * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'watchlearn_movies_';
    //protected $jsonable = ['actors'];
    /* Relations */
    public $belongsToMany =[
        'genres' =>[
            'Watchlearn\Movies\Models\Genre',
            'table' => 'watchlearn_movies_movies_genres',
            'order' => 'genre_title'
        ],
        'actors' =>[
            'Watchlearn\Movies\Models\Actor',
            'table' => 'watchlearn_movies_actors_movies',
            'order' => 'name'
        ]
    ];
    public $attachOne = [
        'poster' => 'System\Models\File'
    ];
    public $attachMany = [
        'movie_gallery' => 'System\Models\File'
    ];
    public static $allowedSortingOptions = array (
        'name desc' => 'Name - desc',
        'name asc' => 'Name - asc',
        'year desc' => 'Year - desc',
        'year asc' => 'Year - asc'
    );
    public function scopeListFrontEnd($query, $options = []){
        extract(array_merge([
            'page' => 1,
            'perPage' => 10,
            'sort' => 'created_at desc',
            'genres' => null,
            'year' => ''
        ], $options));
        if(!is_array($sort)){
            $sort = [$sort];
        }
        foreach ($sort as $_sort){
            if(in_array($_sort, array_keys(self::$allowedSortingOptions))){
                $parts = explode(' ', $_sort);
                if(count($parts) < 2){
                    array_push($parts, 'desc');
                }
                list($sortField, $sortDirection) = $parts;
                $query->orderBy($sortField, $sortDirection);
            }
        }
        if($genres !== null) {
            if(!is_array($genres)){
                $genres = [$genres];
            }
            foreach ($genres as $genre){
                $query->whereHas('genres', function($q) use ($genre){
                    $q->where('id', '=', $genre);
                });
            }
        }
        $lastPage = $query->paginate($perPage, $page)->lastPage();
        if($lastPage < $page){
            $page = 1;
        }
        if($year){
            $query->where('year', '=', $year);
        }
        return $query->paginate($perPage, $page);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm if you implemented, is it not working or do you get any errors or what is not understandable from it can you please share it with us. so we can explain you

Comment: Ajax pagination works as it should, like a "list of pages". But I need it like a "load more" (button).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a onLoadMore() ajax handler in your controller and call that handler (data-request=onLoadMore) with the page number to load (data-request-data={page: page + 1} ).

You then need to return the new paged data from the onLoadMore() handler as a partial update in APPEND mode.

ref. https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/update-partials#appending-prepending

Comment: i've done this before, filters do not work when loading a new page.